# access the sendsms class when button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Creating a simple app for someone that has an android phone. I created a class that sends sms and layout that it accesses. When user presses the button, it should call that particular activity, but it does not work as intended and app crashes. Im new to android, started a moth ago and am in high school. `public class App extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);
    final Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
    //startActivity(i);

   /* View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            if(v==email)
            {
                Intent intentText = new Intent(App.this ,
                        Mail.class);
                App.this.startActivity(intentText);
                //Log.i("Content ", " Main layout ");
            }
            if(v==text)
            {
                Intent intentEmail= new Intent(App.this,
                        Text.class);
                App.this.startActivity(intentEmail);
                //Log.i("Content "," App layout ");
            }
        }
    };
    email.setOnClickListener(handler);
    text.setOnClickListener(handler);*/
    email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intentMail = new Intent(App.this ,
                    Mail.class);
            App.this.startActivity(intentMail);
        }
    });
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intentText = new Intent(App.this ,
                    Text.class);
            App.this.startActivity(intentText);
        }
    });
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(App.this, Mail.class));
    }
});

text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(App.this, Text.class));
    }
});
```

Try this and see if it works? I recently had a similar problem and this fixed it for me. I'm fairly new to Android too, so can't guarentee it'll work. In fairness it looks like a simplified version of what you're already typing. Let me know if it helps at all!